# Dynamically setting TeamCity version numbers based on Gradle file?

Tags: gradle, teamcity

I want to change my build number format in TeamCity Cloud 2020.2.2 using the Gradle file in my android project where my version and build number are stored.

Want to achieve build number

`VERSION_MAJOR+VERSION_MINOR+VERSION_PATCH+Teamcity_Buildcounter` =
`1.1.3.48`

I want Gradle value in TeamCity and once Teamcity Buildcounter is increased update that in the Gradle file and commit? I didn't find a way to do it till now. Any idea how I can achieve this all answer are very old not specific to android

build.gradle

```
def VERSION_MAJOR=1
def VERSION_MINOR=1
def VERSION_PATCH=3

//Create a variable called keystorePropertiesFile, and initialize it to your
//keystore.properties file, in the rootProject folder.
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")

// Initialize a new Properties() object called keystoreProperties.
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()

// Load your keystore.properties file into the keystoreProperties object.
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode VERSION_BUILD
        versionName VERSION_MAJOR + "." + VERSION_MINOR + "." + VERSION_PATCH
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        archivesBaseName = "Appname-v$versionName"

// Rest code continues
```

My settings:
[image: Setting]

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for but this [library](https://github.com/moallemi/gradle-advanced-build-version) might help.

Comment: @YASAN That library just does version number generation which is already done. I think that is irrelevant to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Since build number can use parameters, you can try this:

- change "Build number format" to something like `%VERSION_BY_GRADLE%.%build.counter%`
- give `VERSION_BY_GRADLE` a default value, e.g. "1.0" so config could run
- update it in any step before you need full version number by [sending service message](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/service-messages.html#Adding+or+Changing+a+Build+Parameter) to teamcity  `##teamcity[setParameter name='VERSION_BY_GRADLE' value='put something from your code']` with `echo / Write-Host / print` command
- feel free to experiment, try `%VERSION_NUMBER%` instead of `%VERSION_BY_GRADLE%.%build.counter%` and compose it fully manually